# Conky harmattan is surrounded by the previews wallpaper

Tags: conky

This is an amazing eye-candy but I'm facing a problem. I installed it in my Ubuntu 13.10 64b but Conky is surrounded by a a black box, but it's not a black box at all is the previews wallpaper I had setup. If I change the WP  then the 'black' box changes for a copy of the previews WP. is someone else having this problem?. I'm using Unity

Comment: Are you using Unity or another shell?

Comment: I am using Unity.

Comment: What's in your `conkyrc`?

Comment: Box or fox?please clarify. Also add screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved this in Gnome Shell 3.08 by using the tweak tool, section Desktop, and activating the allow nautilus to manage the desktop option. Maybe the same works with Unity, with unity-tweak-tool or similar, I haven't tested it.

Comment: i'll try this. thx

Comment: i can-t find this option. i just have unity, window manager, appearance, system

Comment: Yep, this works in Gnome, but unity-tweak-tool doesn't have that option.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

First, try adding

own_window no

But ff you already have

```
own_window yes
```

turn it to

```
own_window no
```

If this does not work, then add (or turn `own_window_argb_visual no` to)

```
own_window_argb_visual yes
```

Conky should restart itself automatically after every change you do int the conkyrc file, and it will let you see if it worked.

Comment: Unfortunately,, this doesn't work.